# Docker build fails on COPY or ADD statement for entrypoint, Windows only

Tags: docker, docker-compose, file-permissions, docker-for-windows

I'm creating an entrypoint for a Docker container, and then attempting to run it using a `docker-compose.yml` file.  **This works just fine in Ubuntu and OS X**, but I get a permissions error (without much additional information) in Windows

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.9

MAINTAINER Some Dude <dude@dude.com>

WORKDIR /opt

# Install Compass
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install gcc rubygems ruby-dev
RUN gem update --system
RUN gem install compass

# Install Compass Extensions
RUN gem install compass-blend-modes compass-import-once

# Install glup globally
RUN npm install -g gulp

# Copy the setup file
COPY setup/gulp/docker-gulp-setup.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-gulp-setup.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-gulp-setup.sh

CMD ['gulp']
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml entry:

```
version: '2'

services:

        mycontainer-for-gulp:
                build:
                        context: .
                        dockerfile: Dockerfile.gulp
                volumes:
                        - ./:/opt:Z
                command: /usr/local/bin/docker-gulp-setup.sh
```

Here is the output when the build command is run on Windows:

```
λ docker-compose build mycontainer-for-gulp
Building mycontainer-for-gulp
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
 File "compose\cli\main.py", line 65, in main
 File "compose\cli\main.py", line 117, in perform_command
 File "compose\cli\main.py", line 223, in build
 File "compose\project.py", line 300, in build
 File "compose\service.py", line 742, in build
 File "site-packages\docker\api\build.py", line 55, in build
 File "site-packages\docker\utils\utils.py", line 95, in tar
 File "tarfile.py", line 2023, in add
 File "tarfile.py", line 2052, in addfile
 File "tarfile.py", line 278, in copyfileobj
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
docker-compose returned -1
```

Note that it IS the `COPY` command that's generating the error, because we tried commenting out both that and the `RUN chmod` statement individually.

When I run a raw docker build query:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.gulp .
```

Then I get a bunch of error output as it tries to tar up the current directory.  Basically every file add fails.  Full output is here:

https://gist.github.com/danieltalsky/4cb6bddb6534c46b051230bc45578072

Comment: What happens if you run `docker build -f Dockerfile.gulp .` (removing docker-compose from the equation)

Comment: It returns an error like this for every file in the repo:

`time="2017-02-24T10:21:19-05:00" level=error msg="Can't add file \\\\?\\C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\talentinc\\products\\web\\products\\lib\\x-editable\\inputs-ext\\wysihtml5 to tar: archive/tar: missed writing 1551 bytes"`

Comment: Can you update your question with the full output?

Comment: Ok, I did add it.

Comment: A 1 gig build context is rather large, do you need to send all those files? Perhaps you can shrink it with a .dockerignore file.

Comment: Sure, but it's not using ANY of the files.  And it works fine in OS X.  Also... that's our repo, beast that it is.

Comment: Should have asked earlier, did you check your C drive in the shared drive settings of the docker setup, and then restart the daemon? Didn't think that would be need for a build, but you never know.

Comment: Good question.  Yes all drives have been shared.

Comment: Regarding the log you added to the question later. Do you see the errors appearing immediately after `docker build` is started or "after some time"? I'm asking because I suspect that one of your Windows drives or the internal hyperv disk image is out of space. Also there may be a limitation on build context size in Docker for Windows. So you really should try to use .dockerignore as suggested by BMitch.

Comment: That's a decent idea.  The thing is, there's multiple containers, one running apache, one running a package management tool, and one to run the gulp build.  Only the gulp build is failing this way.

Comment: Had similar behavior, the first file that's failing is the one creating all the havoc (for you its the LICENCE file). Try first adding that to `.dockerignore` and, if successful, try to understand why the file is problematic. For me, the problematic file was a symlink which `docker build` doesn't like.

Comment: @Stav thanks, in my case it was starting with a "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process", I guess it's a quite common error.

Comment: @Stav I ran into similar issue. The root cause was some files unrelated to docker were locked by another process. Using `.dockerignore` fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue when I tried to build the Docker image while the application was still running in the IDE.

**Make sure to shutdown your application before building your image**

Answer (score 0):

Working in PyCharm I had set up my subfolder as 'sources root' (right-click folder name > Mark Directory As > Sources Root). When I removed the subfolder as a sources root this error disappeared